# puppeteer page.authenticate https proxy not work

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, puppeteer

Running puppeteer with Proxy authentication failing.

Puppeteer version: 1.8

Platform / OS version:MacOS 10.13.6

Node.js version:v10.9.0

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors:true,
        devtools:true,
        timeout:3000,
        args: ['--no-sandbox','--proxy-server=xxx:xxx']
     });
     const user='xxx';
     const password='xxx';
     const page = await browser.newPage();
     // await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
     //   'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${user}:${password}`).toString('base64'),
   // });
     await page.authenticate({username:user, password:password});
     await page.goto('https://www.apple.com/');
     let title = await page.title();
     console.log("title:" + title);
     await browser.close();
    })();
```

got error:

```
(node:5858) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED at https://www.apple.com/
at navigate (/xxx/node_modules/_puppeteer@1.8.0@puppeteer/lib/Page.js:622:37)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:5858) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
inside of an async function without a catch block, 
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
(rejection id: 1)
```

Comment: It is a known [issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3253) with Puppeteer. Use https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless:false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors:true,
    devtools:true,
    timeout:3000,
    args: ['--no-sandbox','--proxy-server=https=xxx:xxx']
 });
 const user='xxx';
 const password='xxx';
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.authenticate({username:user, password:password});
 await page.goto('https://www.apple.com/');
 let title = await page.title();
 console.log("title:" + title);
 await browser.close();
})();
```

For me it worked by adding https between the proxy server argument.

Answer (score 1):

Within your args to launch puppeteer,

You can also try this format:

--proxy-server=http=xxx:xxxx

OR

Have you tried setting proxy like this '--proxy-server=https=MyWorkingProxyIP:Port' according to docs https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings ?